# Error de Laravel con Composer y versión de PHP: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version 8

Tags: laravel, composer

Mi sistema (Ubuntu 18.04 con Apache 2) actualizo PHP a la versión 8.0.1.
Tengo Composer 2.0.8.

He intentando actualizar varios *laraveles* que mantengo en versiones 6 y 7, siguiendo esta página:
https://blog.laravel.com/laravel-php-8-support

Con todos, al tratar de iniciar las aplicación tengo el siguiente mensaje en el navegador:

> Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0".

En el ficheros "composer.json", la versión de PHP he probado entre otros:

```
"php": ">= 7.3 || ^8",
"php": "^8",
"php": ">= 8.0",
"php": "8.0.1",
```

En las dependencias cambio *faker* a:

```
"fakerphp/faker" : "^1.9.1",
```

y PHPUnit he probado con:

```
"phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3",
"phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
```

El comando `composer update` functiona correctamente, y ejecute limpiezas de cache: `php artisan optimize:clear`.

Comment: ejecuta echo 8 > .php-version desde consola en el directorio raiz del proyecto. A mi me ha funcionado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El problema se soluciona ejecutando los comandos `composer`acompañados de la opción `--ignore-platform-reqs`. Es decir, podemos recargar el *mapeo de clases*:

```
composer dump-autoload --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Instalar dependencias:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

o actualizarlas:

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Antes de esto, corregir la versión de PHP en uso en `composer.json`, *aunque no se use en el momento, debe servir como referencia de la versión empleada*:

```
"php": "^8.0",
```

---

La versión de PHP actualmente en uso en Linux, la vemos con:

```
php -v
```

Podemos **cambiar entre versiones de PHP disponibles**, en una maquina Linux, con:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```